# Call Graph API C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to build a simple console application in C# that would allow me to call in this case the beta api. I am also trying to call a method delegate method.

This is my main call

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string clientId = <clientID>;
        const string tenantId = <tenantID>;
        const string clientSecret = <secretKey>;
        const string tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        List<string> scopeURL = new List<string>();
        scopeURL.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
        var graphClient = DelegateApp(clientId,tenantId,clientSecret,scopeURL);
        try
        {
            getUsersAsync(graphClient).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This is how i defined my graph call

```
    private static GraphServiceClient DelegateApp(string clientId, string tenantId, string clientSecret, List<string> scope)
    {
        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .Build();

        OnBehalfOfProvider authProvider = new OnBehalfOfProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scope);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
        graphClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";
        return graphClient;
    }
```

And this is what I am trying to call

```
    public async static Task getUsersAsync(GraphServiceClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            var bookingBusiness = await client.BookingBusinesses.Request().GetAsync();
            foreach (var business in bookingBusiness)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(business.DisplayName);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This is the exception I get.
ex.Message = "Code: generalException\r\nMessage: An error occurred sending the request.\r\n"

This happens when i call client.bookingbusinesses.request.getasync();

Comment: Can you authenticate with the graph client using your credentials? I noticed the function you have is called `DelegateApp` however your first function references `NonDelegateApp`.

Comment: Sorry will correct I had two method originally one for Delegate and nonDelegate. but yes i have try

Comment: However I dont get asked to login or anything like that

Comment: If it isn't an authentication/authorization issue, check any inner exceptions and make sure the collection exists in your remote graph.