# Graph API automate delegated access?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, microsoft-graph-api, o365-flow

I want to create a script that interacts with the MS Graph API and has access to everything I have as a user (the user who registered the App). I am using the python O365 library to do so. There are [two types of permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/developer-glossary#permissions) that one can grant an Azure App:

1. Delegated - Request scope access during authentication
2. Application - Role is managed from the Azure App ui

I don't need my script to be able to read ALL files, just those my user has access to, but I DO need my script to be automated. [O365 offers 2 authentication procedures](https://pypi.org/project/O365/#authentication):

1. "authorization" - On behalf of a user
2. "credentials" - The client_id, and client_secret are all you need

which apparently [correspond to the two types of access listed above.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57526395/either-scp-or-roles-claim-need-to-be-present-in-the-token-using-when-application)

Since I don't want to expose every single file in my account to the script, I would prefer to use delegated access just to my user files. But I can't find any examples of how to use delegated ("On behalf of a user") access automatically.

**How can I automatically - ie. without manual input - authenticate a script with delegated (scope-level) access?**

I can't find any examples of this. Is it impossible?

Comment: I have basically the same questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64070047/call-graph-api-c-sharp.

Comment: Delegated permission requires user authentication and a consent. Have you tried enabling resource owner grant for non-interactive login? This means the script passing your password !!!! rather than you login onto a page. This won't probably work if your AAD requires MFA. Also, az CLI has 'az account get-access-token' for any API. You can try using it.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda any sample for the code you are speaking of.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc